# How to remove specific words in database?

Tags: sql, sql-delete

I will try to explain with an explain because it is bit complicated.I would like to remove words from my SQL table if the word's root already exist in table. So my table structure is like this

```
Words  Scores
car       5
book      11
cars       2
pen        10
tool       4
car's      8
tools      2
```

So in this case, since car is root of car's and cars, tool is root of tools, I would like to remove them and add their score on the root word and get my table like this;

```
Words  Scores
car       15
book      11  
pen       10
tool       6
```

Not: if there is "a" in the list then all words that starting with a going to be remove: for this I thought about having if condition like; `if (string[i].Length>=3)` but ofcourse it won't avoid all possibilities maybe there will be word "book"and "booking" so booking is going to be deleted but it is OK.

Comment: What dbms are you using ??

Comment: very well asked. Interesting question.

Comment: hm, this is an interesting question. BUT: It is not an sql question. You need some kind of grammar/spell/speech/whatever-tool to check if a word is a root of another word. you cannot decide this via sql. once you are clear of which words being roots and not, you can update your table.

Comment: @Shyam what makes you think so?

Comment: Because I read it once and it was pretty clear what user was asking. @CodeCaster

Comment: @Shyam that you think you understand a question after reading it once does not make it a good question for Stack Overflow. [Stemming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stemming) is not a trivial problem that is solved with an SQL `LIKE` query.

Comment: it is just a small problem ı am having in my asp.net web app project whih is connected sql database. I though it would be hard with sql,if it was only for a specific word like book ı would use LIKE statatement book% ,which can solve the problem how ever there are many words in table(insertinf from a hypertext) like boats ,boat's  or houses ,house's.So maybe by using select statement I can get all words and scores and then string contain method could be use but ı am not sure, I need your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I can't think of an easier solution if you don't have a relations table containing root and childs, but you can try something like this - In two steps, first step is update the scores, the second delete the childs :

```
UPDATE YourTable t
SET t.Scores =(SELECT sum(s.scores) FROM YourTable s
               WHERE s.words like concat('%',t.words,'%'))
```

**EDIT:** or this

```
update t
set t.score=sum(s.score) 
from YourTable t
INNER JOIN YourTable s
 ON (s.words like concat('%',t.words,'%'))
```

This will update every one to their childs(look alike) total score.

Then delete :

```
DELETE FROM YourTable t
WHERE t.words in(SELECT s.words FROM YourTable s
                 WHERE t.words like concat('%',s.words,'%')
                 AND t.words <> s.words)
```

This will delete all the records that are a child(look alike) of another word. It won't work on any DBMS, so here is another version of it with a join(Update join syntax is different from one db to another):

```
DELETE FROM YourTable t
INNER JOIN YourTable s
 ON(t.words like concat('%',s.words,'%')
    AND t.words <> s.words)
```

You didn't provide your `RDBMS`, so this is an answer for `ANSI-SQL`.
This is untested , so check if it works.

**Edit:** Remeber that without a root-child table, there will be some exceptions that won't work and may lead to unnecessary update/deletion. You have to make rules of when a word is a child of another word, which will have no expection(I don't know if its even possible using sql).

My best suggestion - populate by yourself such table, insert all the root-child options, and use this table for the delete/update , this will ensure no errors will be made.

Comment: thanks for answer when I have implemented code into my project like this http://dpaste.com/2P73MT4 I got an error saying; Operator '%' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'string'

Comment: @infoperto You have a mistake there, you used double quotes on the second `%`

Comment: thanks again ı have fixed it http://dpaste.com/1SF6VB5 but ı get error saying; Incorrect syntax near 't'. for the Line 136:            cmv.ExecuteNonQuery();   Is it wrong to use executenonquery for this sql statement

Comment: What dbms are you using? MySQL/SQL-Server/Oracle ?.. @infoperto

Comment: I am using sql server. http://dpaste.com/2EW1K7M this is a code for deleting database table before each calculation and it works well so I thought would be better use same structure since it works

Comment: @infoperto Did my delete query worked? I'll update the update part with one fixed to sql server.

Comment: @infoperto I updated my answer, take the update with the join and tell me if it works. Also tell me if the delete works.

Comment: I got the same error with updated code. I dont understand what does it mean incorrect syntax near t,near t there is table name(which is written correct) and set.

Comment: and for delete ı got exactly the same error saying incorrect syntax near 't'

Answer (score 1):

Here's a start which finds some common cases. It's reasonable as a first step to consider only words of 3 or more characters.

```
select distinct w2.word from words w inner join words w2
on w.word = w2.word + 's'
    or w.word = w2.word + '''s'
    or w.word = w2.word + 'ing'
    or w.word = w2.word + substring(w2.word, len(w2.word), 1) + 'ed'    
    or w.word = w2.word + substring(w2.word, len(w2.word), 1) + 'y'
where len(w.word) >= 3
```

To delete the derived words:

```
delete w from words w inner join words w2
on w.word = w2.word + 's'
    or w.word = w2.word + '''s'
    or w.word = w2.word + 'ing'
    or w.word = w2.word + substring(w2.word, len(w2.word), 1) + 'ed'    
    or w.word = w2.word + substring(w2.word, len(w2.word), 1) + 'y'
where len(w2.word) >= 3
```

To count the number of words, you could do this: 
I'm sure there is a more elegant way to do this, and will update this post when I find one.
First add a view, or if you can't do this, create a temp table `#root_words` and insert the following into it.

```
create  view root_words as
select distinct w2.word as root_word, w.word as derived_word 
from words w inner join words w2
on w.word = w2.word + 's'
    or w.word = w2.word + '''s'
    or w.word = w2.word + 'ing'
    or w.word = w2.word + substring(w2.word, len(w2.word), 1) + 'ed'    
    or w.word = w2.word + substring(w2.word, len(w2.word), 1) + 'y'
where len(w2.word) >= 3
```

Then this query does a `union` to include words like "dog" which are not derived from any other word. Otherwise they will be missed from the count.

```
select x.root_word, count(*) 
from 
(
    select rw.root_word, rw.derived_word
    from words w
    inner join root_words rw on w.word = rw.root_word
    -- add words which aren't derived from any other word
    union all
    select w.word as root_word, null as derived_word
    from words w
    left join root_words rw on w.word = rw.derived_word
    where rw.root_word is null
) x
group by x.root_word
```

Comment: thank you for your answer delete works very well but how can i sum up the scores of words before deleting?